# AVAudioPlayer interrupting playback with audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur, with NSOSStatusErrorDomain -50

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, nserror

In very specific, but reproducible cases, I'm getting `audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error:` with the following NSError:

`Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"`

This occurs in a game that also uses OpenAL; we're playing sounds using OpenAL, but attempting to leverage hardware AAC decoding. However, the occurence of the above does not appear linked to anything we do in OpenAL.

This happens about 2-3 seconds after we perform scene (game mode) switching -- but only with certain combinations of from-and-to scenes. It is even stranger since we do nothing important audio related on these events. I've verified that we do nothing with `AVAudioPlayer`, but it doesn't seem that anything important is done with OpenAL either.

I've tried to resolve this by releasing the `AVAudioPlayer`, and replacing it with another one that references the same file, uses the same volume and resumes from the same time in the file. However, after a few seconds, this player also throws the aforementioned error. Switching to a new song, on the other hand, creates a fully functional player, that does not have any problems.

My question is: what does error -50 mean in this context, or how would you go about figuring out what it means?

(If it means anything, the game must run at minimum on iOS 3.1.2).

---

We have tried disabling OpenAL part of the code; it did not help.

Audio library code is publicly available at http://libxal.svn.sf.net/svnroot/libxal/trunk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to mess up something on the C++ level. This probably caused memory corruption in AVAudioPlayer without actually crashing the game, and behaving the same on the Simulator and the device. We fixed this and the AVAudioPlayer now works.